# Convert server connection to oracle DB to code

Tags: c#, oracle

I set up a connection to an oracle db using the server explorer in visual studio. The connection works fine and a query set up via new query works also fine and returns data as expected.

I then went to right click the connection and to properties and used the connection like this:

```
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=yyy;User ID=xxx;Password=*******;Unicode=True";
    conn.Open();
```

But if I run this through debug it fails even though I use exactly the connection string given in properties (obviously I put the right pw).

What other information do I need to give when setting up connection in code and where can I extract the information in the server explorer please? The information must be all there, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to download and install ODP from this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

After installation add a reference of the assembly Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Your are good to go after this.

Make sure you include these::

```
using System; 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

Then make connection.

```
class ConnectOracle
{ 
    OracleConnection con; 
    void Connect() 
    { 
        con = new OracleConnection(); 
        con.ConnectionString = "User Id=xxx;Password=*****;Data Source=YYYY"; 
        con.Open(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle ::- " + con.ServerVersion); 
    }

    void Close() 
    {
        con.Close(); 
        con.Dispose(); 
    } 

    static void Main() 
    { 
        Example OraTest= new OraTest(); 
        OraTest.Connect(); 
        OraTest.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

You can make more logging possible with this as well.

Comment: ok, thanks. But how is the server explorer doing it? I mean visual studio has all it needs, no?

Comment: are you connecting it by VS server explorer.